# Stacked column chart with irregular date time interval

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a stacked column chart with irregular datetime on x-axis. The date time interval can be any. Basically our crawler insert data on regular interval from different api but there are cases where it fails for certain dates. So the date time is mostly irregular.

Have a look at below example.

[image]

- **I need to remove those points which are automatically added by
  highchart.**
- **I need to place exact point date on x axis.**
- **I need the
  alignment of x axis with column. Currently the dates on x-axis are
  not aligned.**

```js
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        type: "column",
    },
    title: {
        text: ""
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: "datetime",
        tickLength: 0,        
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: "Keywords"
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            style: {
                fontWeight: "bold",
                color: "gray"
            }
        },
        opposite: false
    },
    legend: {
        backgroundColor: "white",
        borderColor: "#CCC",
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: false
    },
     plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            },            
        },
    series: [{
        name: "Ranked on Page 3",
        data: [{
            y: 2,
            x: 1449532800000,
            pointDate: 1449532800000
        }, {
            y: 4,
            x: 1450137600000,
            pointDate: 1450137600000
        }, {
            y: 3,
            x: 1450742400000,
            pointDate: 1450742400000
        }, {
            y: 3,
            x: 1451347200000,
            pointDate: 1451347200000
        }, {
            y: 2,
            x: 1454025600000,
            pointDate: 1454025600000
        }],
        maxPointWidth: 100
    }, {
        name: "Ranked on Page 2",
        data: [{
            y: 1,
            x: 1449532800000,
            pointDate: 1449532800000
        }],
        maxPointWidth: 100
    }, {
        name: "Ranked on Page 1",
        data: [{
            y: 2,
            x: 1454025600000,
            pointDate: 1454025600000
        }],
        maxPointWidth: 100
    }],
    colors: ["#6662AC", "#57B3C8", "#F7971E"]
        });
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

To play with the actual data and output : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mj7rj92n/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What points are "automatically added by highchart"? What does that mean?

Comment: It means that, I am only passing 5 dates to the chart and between 28 Dec to 1 Feb there are no data points. It is automatically considering the 7 days date interval.

Comment: So you are saying you want equal distance between all points? Regardless of the difference in time.

Comment: No i don't need that points(4 Jan, 11 Jan , 18 Jan, 25 Jan) at all. OR Display only those dates of point dates

Comment: If I am not wrong, J-D wants to show only those dates which are shown on  bar hover. That date should be show on x-axis as plot date

Comment: To do what you explained I would use `xAxis.categories`. That allows you removing extra dates on xAxis, and points will be aligned directly with labels. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/52seb35w/4/ (note that "orange" point requires `x` value - index of the category where should be placed.

Comment: @Paweł Fus : This graph and data are just example. I have maximum 3 years of data. So the number of points can be anything. How can i make a decision to add x value on  "orange" point. When and where it require x value and why?

Comment: Oh, so many points. It won't work with categories. In that case, you should use Highstock with `ordinal` axis, as answered below. One of the reasons of Highstock existence is `ordinal` axis feature.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with [Highstock](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal), using:

```
xAxis.ordinal = true
```

Check this SO answer: [Highcharts - Column chart with empty columns for date in x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830955/highcharts-column-chart-with-empty-columns-for-date-in-x-axis)

Comment: I have already tried this but this doesn't work with HighChart. Please note that this is not HighStock its a HighChart

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you can't use highstock?